# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) range should be read as NOTHING in the next worksheet loop

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with an "if range is nothing then" part of my code.

Let's say I have 4 worksheets:

- Project 1 worksheet - should be skipped, filtered range is nothing, project number not in raw file
- Project 2 worksheet - code needs to run, fitlered range is not nothing, project number exists
- Project 3 worksheet - should be skipped, filtered range is nothing, project number not in raw file
- Project 4 worksheet - code needs to run, fitlered range is not nothing, project number exists

Project 3 is not being skipped, the not nothing range of the last worksheet (Project 2) is being read.
Kindly advise.

Code:

```
' dim declarations...
' set assignments....

    If Worksheets("Raw").AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Worksheets("Raw").AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

    With ws_raw
        int_last_row_of_raw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        int_last_col_of_raw = 16
        Set rng_raw = .Range("A2", .Cells(int_last_row_of_raw, int_last_col_of_raw))
    End With

    With ws_raw.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2"), Order:=xlAscending
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("L2"), Order:=xlDescending
            .SetRange rng_raw
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
    End With

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Not ws Is ws_raw _
            And Not ws Is ws_master_tracker _
            And Not ws Is ws_title_page _
            And Not ws Is ws_sample _
            And Not ws Is ws_closing _
            And Not ws Is ws_ref _
            And Not ws Is ws_pdf_template _
            And Not ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then

            project_name = ws.Range("E3").Value

            With rng_raw
                    .AutoFilter 1, project_name
            End With


            On Error Resume Next
                Set rng_filtered_raw = ws_raw.Range("J3", ws_raw.Cells(int_last_row_of_raw, int_last_col_of_raw)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0

            ' not doing its thing on project 3 worksheet
            If rng_filtered_raw Is Nothing Then
                If project_name = "" Then
                    project_name = "[BLANK]"
                End If
                not_found_project_numbers = not_found_project_numbers & ws.Name & " : " & project_name & vbNewLine
                MsgBox ("skipped, project number not found, moving to the next ws")
            Else
                int_last_row_of_ws = 46
                For int_current_row_of_ws = 11 To int_last_row_of_ws

                    cell_value = ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 3).Value

                    Select Case cell_value

                        'Concept Stage
                        Case Is = "Creation,Overview,Concept,Scope,Potential"
                            module_to_look_for = "Project Creation"

                        Case Is = "Product Briefing !"

                        ' 20 or 30 more cases

                        ' Others that are manually typed
                        Case Else
                            module_to_look_for = "MANUAL"

                    End Select

                    If Not rng_filtered_raw Is Nothing Then
                        If module_to_look_for = "MANUAL" Then
                            ' Do nothing
                            ' Highlight cell, etc.
                        Else
                            look_up_result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(module_to_look_for, rng_filtered_raw, 3, False)
                            If look_up_result = "" Then
                                ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 56).Value = "Blank Date!"
                            Else
                                ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 56).Value = look_up_result
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next int_current_row_of_ws
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
```

Comment: Try adding `Set rng_filtered_raw = Nothing` before the `On Error Resume` statement in the loop. Otherwise, the range object will not be nothing when the assignment of it fails due to `On Error Resume Next`, rather it will remain the same as in the previous iteration and your conditional statement below to catch that will not work. Moreover, here's a pointer why some people might have downvoted your question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @Miqi190 not that it matters, I guess you might have missed it but I forgot to include rng_raw.AutoFilter 1, project_name i Edited my code above. And thank you! setting the range to nothing worked. I am somehow disappointed of the downvoting because I just want to be better with newbie questions since I am a newbie but I will surely review my questions moving forward, making them more downvoting resistant. I just saved the link you shared in my bookmarks bar and will follow the guidelines here moving forward..

Comment: I am not really good in asking clear and perfect questions but I will work on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand a bit on my comment above, which seems to have done the trick:

Due to `On Error Resume Next` whenever the the range object cannot be set, the range object is **not** set to nothing, rather it just remains set to whatever it was set to in the previous iteration of the loop. (Without the `On Error Resume Next` statement, you would get a run-time error whenever the `rng_filtered_raw` range object cannot be set). For this reason, your conditional statement below to catch when the range object is nothing does not work as intended.

Hence, adding `Set rng_filtered_raw = Nothing` before the `On Error Resume Next` statement should fix this problem.

Comment: Do you recommend removing the On Error Resume Next catcher? If so, what's a better way? I know this is a different topic but I can't help myself to ask (since you're still online).

Comment: Well, it depends. You would have to refactor your code to get rid of it, e.g. by checking in some other way if the range you're working with exists on the current loop sheet. `On Error Resume Next` does have its valid use cases and your method of checking the range in question does make sense, so I'd probably keep it in this case.

Comment: I think I will stick to it until I finish my whole project. If I somehow leveled up in VBA then I will consider playing with it more. :)